# Wordpress Theme fails on transfer to live site

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have a live site using WordPress.  I created a test folder on this site to develop a WordPress theme.  However when I copy over the theme folder from the test to the live sites theme folder and activate this new theme I get issues.  All that shows is the title of the site.  The version is the same 3.3.1.  Has anyone come across this?  What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Do you have a link to the staging or live environment? When you View Source on the live environment, what's the last line of HTML you see? My guess is there's a PHP error due to something in effect on the live environment that is stopping processing of the theme files.

Comment: You might try adding this code at the top of your `header.php` theme file. If it is a PHP error, this ought to force your server to display the error and line number: `<?php ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @SetSailMedia Thank you for the error trick.  Apparently calling the google search box was undefined and caused everything to die.  Thank you so much for the tip

Comment: Post that as an answer and i will mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is there's a PHP error due to something in effect on the live environment that is stopping processing of the theme files.

You might try adding this code at the top of your header.php theme file. If it is a PHP error, this ought to force your server to display the error and line number:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```